# How to generalize object creation in C++ using variadic templates?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, generic-programming

I am trying to make a generic factory method in C++, that can create an instance of one of many (but finite number of) objects. Each of the objects require different types of parameters to construct so I want the method to somehow infer the desired type and not want to have the user specify it explicitly.

Here's some code to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A(int x, int y) {
        cout << "A(" << x << ", " << y << ")\n";
    }
};

class B {
public:
    B(float a, float b) {
        cout << "B(" << a << ", " << b << ")\n";
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
T * Make(Ts... vs) {
    puts(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__); // __FUNCSIG__ or __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    return new T{ vs... };
}
```

Now the code in, say, `main` function can create objects of type `A *` and `B *` by invoking `Make` like this:

```
A *a = Make<A>(3, 4);
B *b = Make<B>(3.14f, 6.28f);
```

Is there a way I can extend this code to enable other functions to call `Make` without having to explicitly specify whether they want an instance of `A *` or `B *` ? For example,

```
A * a = Make(3, 4); // (int, int)
B * b = Make(3.14f, 6.28f); // (float, float)
```

I understand function templates get instantiated using argument type deduction and return type is not involved in this. However, the compiler will not do any type conversions. So `Make(int, int)` is definitely a different instance from `Make(float, float)` and I want to be able to leverage this to map the function definition to the right return type.

Here's what I tried:

- defining an explicit instantiation

  ```
  template A * Make(int x, int y);
  ```
- defining a specialization

  ```
  template<>
  A * Make<A, int, int>(int x, int y);
  ```

Both didn't work as expected. Any ideas on how this can be achieved ?

Comment: OT: It would be better to use perfect forwarding in your make function: `T* Make(Ts&&... vs)` and `return new T{std::forward<Ts>(vs)...};`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a `Maker` helper template that registers which classes are allowed, although I don't exactly know how to disable the base template:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct Maker {
    using type = void;
};

template <>
struct Maker<int, int> {
    using type = A;
};

template <>
struct Maker<float, float> {
    using type = B;
};

template<typename... Ts, typename T=typename Maker<Ts...>::type>
T * Make(Ts... vs) {
    puts(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__); // __FUNCSIG__ or __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    return new T{ vs... };
}

int main() {
    A * a = Make(3, 4); // (int, int)
    B * b = Make(3.14f, 6.28f); // (float, float)
}
```

Comment: That works great! I guess the base template can be written to have an empty `struct Maker {}` without any type field, which can then be used with enable_if (from type_traits) so that the definition for Make would be available only for known types.

Comment: Oh, if you compile in C++14 mode you can leave off `using type = void`. (compiles for the given example and throws an error for eg `Make()`)

Comment: @Botje: even in C++11. (but not before because of variadic template and default template parameter for function)

Answer (score 3):

You might give needed information to the factory, set of class to construct, and needed arguments(*).

(*): (Note: if your classes has correct properties, you might even detect constructor's arguments automatically with [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get).

```
template <typename ... Sigs> struct Maker : Maker<Sigs>...
{
    using Maker<Sigs>::operator ()...;

    // Do we want to accept conversions or not in non ambiguous cases ?
    //template <typename ... Ts> operator()(Ts/*&&*/...) const = delete;
};

template <class C, typename ... Args> struct Maker<C(Args...)>
{
    C operator()(Args... args) const {
        puts(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__); // __FUNCSIG__ or __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
        return C(std::forward<Args>(args)...); // not {} to avoid initializer_list constructor
    }
};
```

And then the factory instance:

```
constexpr Maker<A(int, int), B(float, float)> Make{};
```

With usage:

```
A a = Make(3, 4); // (int, int)
B b = Make(3.14f, 6.28f); // (float, float)
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d80c3ca261c1155c)

Comment: That is fascinating. In the line `constexpr Maker<A(int, int), B(float, float)> Make{};` are the template arguments (e.g., `A(int, int)`) function types ?

Comment: As for `std::function`, signature of function